# Can I submit an Apache Beam job using DirectRunner to a local VM

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to learn Apache Beam but because I'm having so much trouble running JdbcIo in Windows that I installed a Linux distro as a VirtualBox VM and installed Apache Beam via pip install.

Now my question: is there a way to keep writting my pipeline using VSCode on Windows and submit/delegate the beam execution to the Linux VM using DirectRunner or in any other way?

Sorry if the question doesn't make too much sense. I'm just having trouble figuring out the Apache Beam architecture from the documentation.

Additionally, I also tried installing an Apache Beam docker container via Docker Desktop on Windows but couldn't even get the container to run.

Apache Beam documentation overall seems very scarce for developers just starting on this platform, like myself.

Comment: Have you tried to use https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial? It basically use vscode as a client on windows but all your code run in VM.